# PHPSpreadsheet & CodeIgniter -> Message: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I'm having trouble creating a test file using the PHPSpreadsheet library in CodeIgniter. When I run the code below I get the error message:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
>
> Filename: C:\wamp64\www\din-din\application\controllers\home.php
>
> Line Number: 17
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\din-din\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Could you explain what happens?

The test was performed with PHP 5.6.35 and 7.2.4, using WampServer64 3.1.3 and CodeIgniter in version 3.1.9! The PHPSpreadsheet library was installed via composer according to the documentation in https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Thank you!

CODE:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
        use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('hello_world.xlsx');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`use`, as a means to import or alias a namespace, cannot be made inside function scope. To quote the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

The convention is to place `use` as the very first instructions in your file, before anything else: constant declaration, function definition, etc. Your code would be re-written as:

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    // ...
```

You *could* put the `use` after the `defined()`, or after the `class` (ie at the bottom of the file), but that would be quite unusual.

Two notes:

1. There is a `use` operator that imports variables into Closure, like so `function () use ($var) { ... }`. The same keyword, but in that lexical context it's not related to namespacing.
2. If you're using a recent version of PHP, you can use namespace grouping to save yourself some typing: `use PHPOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\{Spreadsheet, Writer\Xlsx}`

Comment: Thank you, Bishop!

That was exactly what happened. When putting the use shortly after the <?php the problem has been solved. My confusion occurred because until then I had not used "use" and so I was lost!

Once again, thank you!